# CopyOnWriteArrayList index starts from 1

Tags: java, copyonwritearraylist

Do you have any idea about why index in a CopyOnWriteArrayList starts from 1? It says that the list has 14 items and imageDetailsList.get(0) throws a NullPointerException

And this is how I populate the list

```
public List<ImageDetails> generate(List<Product> productList){
     List<ImageDetails> imageDetailsList = new CopyOnWriteArrayList();
     productList.parallelStream().forEach(product -> {
          imageDetailsList.add(imageDetailsCreator.create(product));
     });
     return imageDetailsList;
}
```

[image]

Comment: 1. Index doesn't start from 1, it starts from 0. It is just how the debugger is showing it. If it wasn't starting from 0 it would be violating the contract of `List` interface. 2. If there was no item at requested index, it would be throwing `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, not `NullPointerException`, as stated in the JavaDoc of `get` method. 3. Your list is probably null.

Comment: you're adding to productKeyPointsList instead of imageDetailsList

Comment: So it is not shown in debugger because the value at index 0 is null?

Comment: Also, it's probably not a good idea to add to a CopyOnWriteArrayList one item at a time. Use a copy constructor or addAll.

Comment: Actually, I was slightly wrong. The debbuger should show the first element starting at 0. What I have noticed is that IntelliJ 2016.3 doesn't show null elements in arrays and lists. I have never seen that happen before - maybe it's a new bug? Anyway, answering your question, the element at index 0 is null so the first `add` call must have added null.